# prometheus ConstLabels take value

Tags: go, scope, prometheus

I'm new to Golang and maybe my question is simple, but I've tried many ways to do this.
I am trying to write a simple exporter for prometheus.
My code takes a metric from the gitlab API and I want it to add only ConstLabels.
My code:

```
func enqueueJob() {
    for {
        dat, err := getJobData()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        jobsInQueues.Set(dat[0].QueuedDuration)
    }

}

var jobsInQueues = promauto.NewGauge(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Name:        "A_jobs_panding",
        Help:        "A_Jobs Pending",
        ConstLabels: prometheus.Labels{"name": dat[0].Name},
    },
)

func main() {
    enqueueJob()
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":2112", nil)
}
```

The question is how can I pass to jobsInQueues, dat[0].Name from the getJobData() function
getJobData returns a Job struct?

```
type Job struct {
    ID             int      `json:"id"`
    Status         string   `json:"status"`
    Stage          string   `json:"stage"`
    Name           string   `json:"name"`
    QueuedDuration float64  `json:"queued_duration"`
    TagList        []string `json:"tag_list"`
}
```

If you define var dat, err = getJobData() outside of the function, it doesn't update the value of Name outside of for and I understand that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, `ConstLabels` are a set of labels (=key-value pairs) that are present on the metric and cannot be changed. It seems you'd like to have a label where the value differs per execution.

If so, `ConstLabels` is not what you're looking for. Instead, you should be looking at using a `GaugeVec` (gauge vector) with a label `name`.

Define your metric as such:

```golang
var jobsInQueues = promauto.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Name: "A_jobs_panding",
        Help: "A_Jobs Pending",
    },
    []string{"name"},
)
```

and then, set the gauge by providing the name an value from `getJobData`:

```golang
func enqueueJob() {
    for {
        dat, err := getJobData()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        jobsInQueues.With(prometheus.Labels{
            "name": dat[0].Name,
        }).Set(dat[0].QueuedDuration)
    }

}
```

Note that `enqueueJob` is a blocking operation in your code, so it will never get around to bringing up the HTTP server. You'll want to run either the `enqueueJob` or `http.ListenAndServe` invocations on their own goroutine. Also, it's worth considering the potential distinct names returned from the Gitlab API and how they affect your metric's cardinality.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw the NewGaugeVex, but apparently I did not understand how it works correctly.
And also thanks, I will take into account your remark about the blocking function